Can not send USDT on BEP20 chain using Web3 on python
So I wanted to transfer USDT from wallet to another using web3 but I couldnt make it like this! I am using mainnet.
The transaction I want<-- the transaction i want
The transaction I get<-- the transaction i get
how to solve?
    tx = usdt_contract.functions.transfer(head_wallet2, amount2).build_transaction({
        'from': user_wallet_address,
        'nonce': nonce,
        'gas': 34515,
        'gasPrice': web3.to_wei('1', 'gwei')
    })

here is the transfer function idk why its not working
SOLVED!!

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/166276/can-not-send-usdt-on-bep20-chain-using-web3-on-python/ Solved thanks for that man!!!!
